# Using the Groovy Sql object

Tags: sql, groovy

I'm trying to do some basic queries using the groovy.sql.Sql object, and I'm getting a SQLException that I can't seem to diagnose or make go away.  I've reduced it to the simplest case, and I'm still seeing the problem.  My code:

```
import groovy.sql.Sql

def bodyText
def sql = Sql.newInstance("jdbc:oracle:thin:@192.168.X.Y:1521:hostname",
                          "user", "passwd", "oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver")

sql.eachRow('select * from t_email_recipients') { row ->
  assert row.body != null
  java.sql.Clob clob = (java.sql.Clob) row.body
  bodyText = clob.getAsciiStream().getText()
  println bodyText
}
```

I had a version of this working earlier, but now all is seem to get are something like:

```
Caught: java.sql.SQLException: Invalid column name
        at sqlTest$_run_closure1.doCall(sqlTest.groovy:14)
        at sqlTest.run(sqlTest.groovy:13)
```

Anyone have any ideas here?  I'm using groovy 1.7.4, and jdk 1.6.0_12.

Comment: what does that table look like?  the error is telling you there is no column named 'body' on the table named 't_email_recipients'.  I'm guessing it's not that simple though.

Comment: Nope, not that simple.  There is a body column, of type clob.  There's also a pk, and a few other strings.

Comment: what do you get when you "println row"?  I use groovy sql all the time, and I don't see a problem with your snippet.  I'm thinking the real problem is being masked...

Comment: The error is in line 14 but you have provided a script with only 12 lines. Maybe you could share the code as is...

Comment: I'm going to try this again in Groovy, now that I have it working in Java.  I'll post updated code once I've tried that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that the exception says `Invalid column name` and the only column you're accessing is `body`, my first guess is that there's no such column. However you've indicated in the comments that there is such a column and moreover, you've asserted the presence of this column in the line preceding that which throws the exception

```
assert row.body != null
```

So it seems impossible that this code would throw this exception, so my best guess is that you've modified the code shown here is somehow different from the code that is actually throwing the exception - perhaps you didn't want to post the real code because it's too complex or for IP/privacy reasons.

If I'm right, van you check that this code really is functionally identical to the real code, because it seems impossible to me that this code would throw the given exception.

Comment: Yeah, there were actually two issues here, and I caused the second, which you noted, when I tried to solve the first.  

I backed off and tried to solve this in Java, and only then noted that Matcher & Pattern capture groups don't seem to work unless you call matcher.groupCount() before you call matcher.group(n).

Tired eyes led to the rest of my issues...

Answer (score 1):

You could use something like this

```
  clob?.asciiStream.text
```